# What do /+ and +/ indicate in D?

Tags: comments, d

In some of the Derelict source code, I see some blocks that are surrounded by `/+` and `+/`, like so:

```
/+ other
alias FTC_MruNodeRec*       FTC_MruNode;
alias FTC_MruListRec*       FTC_MruList;
alias FTC_MruListClassRec*  FTC_MruListClass;
+/
```

(Just an example, of course.) What are these? They look like comments, but the content looks like valid code. I'm not able to find anything on Google due to `/+` not being a useful search string. Any help?

Comment: See also http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/lex.html for a description of D's grammar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are comments, just like `/*` and `*/` in C/C++. The different is that `/+` and `+/` nest, while the other versions do not.

For example, this entire line is a comment.

```
/+ A /+ B +/ C +/
```

But with `/* */`, the `C` and closing `*/` is uncommented:

```
/* A /* B */ C */
```

`/+ +/` helps a lot when you need to comment out large blocks of code.

Comment: That explains the huge blocks of code commented out (which do indeed contain existing traditional multiline comments). Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

They're the same as `/*` and `*/`, but they can be nested, e.g.:

```
/+ These are /+ all +/ commented +/
```